# How to copy 'each' json to span id?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Checking with the console gives it all the results:

number

number

number...

I want to change it, and instead of the console,
it will show all the results on id: channellist

http://jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/79/

```
<span id="channellist"></span>

var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var url = 'http://***:8080/***.php?username=***&password=***';

$.ajax({
'url': yql_url,
//remove this line later
'data': {
'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="'+url+'"',
'format': 'json',
'jsonCompat': 'new',
 },
'dataType': 'json',
'success': function(response){
console.log(response);
var res = response.query.results.json;
var keys = Object.keys(res.available_channels);

for(var i =0;i< keys.length;i++){
var num = res.available_channels[keys[i]].num;
//works with console
console.log(res.available_channels[keys[i]].num);
//but i want to paste on span
$('#channellist').html(num);
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var $channellist = $('#channellist');
$channellist.html($channellist.html() + num);
```

If you want each number on a new line you can add `+ '<br/>'` after the `+ num`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

`$('#channellist').append(num);`

To add new line concat a `<br>`

`$('#channellist').append(num+"<br>");`

if you use `html()` it will replace but it you use `.append()` it will add up.